# List of versions of dependency with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a dependency which looks like:

```
compile("group:artifact:+")
```

I want specify its version explicitly. Is it possible to get list of all versions of dependency in remote repository somehow with Gradle command?

Answer (score 1):

I got your issue. I think we cannot get all the list of versions of dependency in remote repository. But if we specify the version as:

```
 compile("group:artifact:mainversion.+")
```

we will get all the versions artifact>=mainversion.0 to compile the project.
For example :

```
compile 'org.infinispan:infinispan-core:6.+'
```

Here the he build script states that any infinispan-core >= 6.0 is required to compile the project.
Hope I am clear. Reach out here for any queries.